# How to recover mails of deleted mail account from .thunderbird directory?

Tags: thunderbird, data-recovery, email-client, gmail-imap

I was using a gmail account. Now my TL deleted that gmail account. I was using mozilla thunderbird as mail client. Also it got disappeared from my mozilla thunderbird . but I found that all those mails are stored in .thunderbird folder. How can I restore all those mails? Its stored in .thunderbird/6s4amxw6.default/ImapMail/imap.googlemail.com/INBOX , an XML like file.How can I recover mails from that file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these Steps

1) Turn off Thunderbird

2) Using your OS, copy the file Trash and the file with the same name as the folder in which those messages were last to a safe location outside your [profile](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder#Thunderbird)

3) Download [Thunderbird Reset Status](http://apveening.a61.nl/software/tbrststs.zip) and run it on the two files ,about this tool can be found over [here](http://apveening.a61.nl/software/)

4) Restart Thunderbird and import the resulting .mbx files using the [MboxImport](http://www.extensionsmirror.nl/index.php?showtopic=2074) extension

Note :

To work in your profile, if you are using Windows, you need to set Windows to "View hidden files and folders" and to not "Hide extensions for known file types".

For more info refer [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Undelete_a_message)

Hope it helps

Comment: http://home.telfort.nl/sp712874/software/tbrststs.zip    . Its 404

Comment: @Harikrishnan updated link check it out